# Laravel creates a new session when opening facebook to login from my app

Tags: facebook, laravel, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

App has been running for a while and I'm adding facebook login now
So basically when my app starts (running ionic with Laravel 4.2 at the back), it fetches the csrf_token from the server. 
When I click on the facebook login it takes me to the inApp browser to login from there. Login gets approved by facebook but now the problem is that somehow laravel loses track of this session and changes the csrf token. 
What can I do to make Laravel keep the same session in the backend? Why is it even creating a new one/changing the token?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So your app runs outside of the in-app browser before login? Then most likely the session id is not transfered correctly, when login is handled in the in-app browser.

Comment: The app loads first (angular way and before anything get the csrf token from the server) then the in-app browser opens for the login